# Fanfiction Harry kills the Dursleys

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry is insane and killed the Dursleys. He's found by Voldemort and his Death Eaters in the house. He talks in rhymes I think. His owl is dead from his uncle who shot it. Voldemort takes him and tries to heal him. Along the way they find out Harry's got split personalities whose names are Ghost, James, Boy, Rose, and Matthias. That's all I can remember. Does anyone know the name of this fanfiction story?

Comment: Does Harry have a goatee? If so, it could be his evil-self from the Mirror universe, because this doesn't sound like the one we know from the books :D My +1 nontheless for the interesting story, hope you find it.

Comment: At first, I was thinking "Broken Mind, Fractured Soul", which has Boy and Rose and Silas in the first few chapters, but he gets to Hogwarts without killing the Dursleys.

Comment: First this and then https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188783/85755

Answer (score 2):

The fanfiction is called **"[A Cleansing Touch](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4392895/1/A-Cleansing-Touch)"** by Sin Maxwell and Co.

> It is the summer after Voldemort's rebirth and he decides to go and collect the Boy-Who-Lived. When he gets there though, all is not well with our hero. Can Voldemort offer Harry a cleansing touch or will the teen be lost to insanity for good?